# I have 2 Achartengine XYSeries problems

Tags: eclipse, windows-8, achartengine

I’m having 2 problems with a simple XYSeries line graph.

1. When the absolute value of the difference between the last plotted point and the next plotted point is less than 11 the label on the next plotted point goes missing. I want all the labels to display.
2. I have some (not all) missing vertical grid lines and don’t see why. I want a vertical grid line for every XY coordinate.

Thanks for the help. Here's the code.

```
 String glucoseLegendText = getString(R.string.glucose_legend_text);
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(glucoseLegendText);

        datasource = new HistoryDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        Cursor c = datasource.getQuery();
        c.moveToFirst();
        int cnt = c.getCount();
        int minValue = 0;
        int maxValue = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            int glucoseValue = c.getInt(2);
            series.add(i, glucoseValue);
            if (i == 0 || glucoseValue < minValue)
                minValue = glucoseValue;
            if (glucoseValue > maxValue)
                maxValue = glucoseValue;
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        datasource.close();

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(series);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        renderer.setLineWidth(3);
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(15);
        renderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.LEFT);

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(cnt); // to control number of grid lines
        mRenderer.setYLabels(cnt); // to control number of grid lines
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(5);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(minValue - 2);  // buffer bottom
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(maxValue + 3);  // buffer top

        // Populate the X labels with the dates and times
        c.moveToFirst();
        for (int d = 0; d < cnt; d++) {
            timeStamp = c.getString(1);
            date = timeStamp.substring(0, 5);
            time = timeStamp.substring(9, 14);
            if (date.equals(dateLast)) {
                mRenderer.addXTextLabel(d, "\n" + time);
            } else
                mRenderer.addXTextLabel(d, "\n" + time + "\n" + date);

            dateLast = date;
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        c.close();

        GraphicalView gview = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset,
                mRenderer, "");

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Chart);
        layout.addView(gview);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can control the labels display using

```
renderer.setXLabels(approximateNumberOfLabels);
```

For the second question, the grid lines are displayed along the labels.

Comment: Thanks for trying Dan but XYSeriesRenderer renderer has no method setXlabels and as you can see in the code I'm already using XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer.setXlabels(cnt) to no effect on my problems. Note: in my code the approximateNumberOfLabels = cnt.

Comment: It took you a month to come up with this conclusion.

Comment: A bit off topic but for some reason my stackoverflow email notification didn't work and with all my other development I just got around to see your answer. As I said, thanx anyway and of course I'll be very interested if someone comes up with a workable solution.